# Why 64 bit software is heavy on 64 bit Windows 10 Operating System?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am using an old computer and its system specifications are as follows:

- Processor: Core 2 duo E7500-Seventh gen
- Physical Memory: 3 Gb
- Mechanical Hard Drive capacity 500 Gb
- Windows 10 64 bit

I installed Pycharm by JetBrains-64 bit version and the computer was not even operable. Everything lagged and every application was literally throwing an  `App Not Responding Error`.

I immediately uninstalled that software and the speed of the machine was restored to moderate if not its best.

Today I decided to install a similar software from JetBrains called IntelliJIDEA except that this one was 32-bit.

The machine's speed hasnt't been affected despite running Visual Studio alongside it.

So I expected the 64-bit software to utilise the better RAM and perform optimum but then the 32 bit version which uses less of the RAM is friendly to the speed of this machine.

Can someone please share a professional explanation as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

On a 64bits program, pointers use twice as many memory (8 bytes instead of 4), then such a program needs more memory.

The advantage is that a 64bits program can use more than 3GB if needed.

If your system start to need more that your 3GB physical memory, memory swapping starts, and the system become less responsive.